# oracle java installer fails with licence not accepted

Tags: upgrade, java, oracle

G'day all,

I am running Ubuntu 12.04
When trying to upgrade the oracle java installer from the webupd8team ppa I get an error that says I declined to accept the licence.
I am never offered the option of accepting the licence.
The installer has been a great way to install and keep Oracle java up to date.
I'd like to keep using it.

Any fixes?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you running the installation? Through synaptic? Through terminal?

Comment: I use the Update Manager GUI and install all recommended updates.

Comment: I now uncheck the box next to the Java Installer so that the other updates go ahead. The Java installer is downloaded but not installed.

Comment: Try updating it via the Synaptic package manager or the terminal while I file a bug.

Comment: I'm assuming it did let you accept when you installed it? What was the package name?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue via Update Manager and it would not present the version 12.10 upgrade either. I updated the package through the shell with apt and was presented a dialog to accept the license. It worked fine. I re-launched Update Manager and was able to proceed with the version upgrade.

EDIT: The package name was oracle-java7-installer

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a link to this package ? I couldn't find it in standard PPA.